# UPDATE con PDO en función PHP no funciona

Tags: php, pdo

**Actualización 2**: He metido un formulario para acceder directamente a PHP y ver si lo que falla es ese archivo o el JS y efectivamente desde el formulario se hace el UPDATE correctamente. El fallo debería estar en el JS y el Ajax supongo. Por la consola sé que el parámetro que entra en JS es el correcto.

**Actualización**: He rediseñado el código para que la función llame a JavaScript y esta mande los datos a PHP con Ajax como me ha indicado un usuario, pero sigue sin realizar el UPDATE.

Php donde se genera el Html que llama a la función:

```
foreach($libros as $libro){
                     echo  "<div class='column'>";
                      echo "<div class='card card-equal-height'>";
                        echo "<div class='card-image form_photo'>";
                          echo "<figure class='image is-4by3'>";
                            echo "<img src='".$libro['imagen']."'>";
                          echo "</figure>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='card-content'>";
                          echo "<p class='title is-5 has-text-centered'>". $libro['titulo'] ."</p>";
                            echo "<p class='subtitle is-6 has-text-centered'>". $libro['autor']."</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='card-footer level-item'>";
                                  echo "<a href='' onclick='marcarLeido(".$libro['isbn'].")'><p class='card-footer-item'>";
                                  echo "<i class='fas fa-bookmark'></i>";
                                   echo "<span>&nbsp;Leído</a></span></p></a>";
                                  echo "<a href=''><p class='card-footer-item'>";
                                  echo "<i class='fas fa-paper-plane'></i>";
                                    echo "<span>&nbsp; Enviar</a></span></p>";
                               echo  "</div></div></div>";
                    }
```

Mi archivo .js:

```
function marcarLeido(isbn) {

var url = 'marcarLeido.php';
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    isbn

  },
  success: function (response) {
    console.log("JS ok");

    

  }
});
```

}

Php que recibe el POST y realiza el update:

```
<?php session_start(); ?> <!DOCTYPE html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> </head> <?php
    if (isset($_POST['isbn']) ) {
        include("funcionesPDO.php");

        $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];

        $conex = conectar();

        $stmt = $conex->prepare("UPDATE books SET leido = 1 WHERE isbn = :id AND id_usuario = :par");
        $stmt->bindValue(':par', $_SESSION['usuario_id']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $isbn);
        $stmt->execute();

        desconectar($conex);

    } ?> </p> <!-- Scripts--> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"
></script>   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"
></script>   <script src="_javascript/main.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

Tengo una lista de libros que muestro en el HTML como tarjetas con sus datos más un botón. Quiero que al darle a ese botón cambie el valor de un campo en la base de datos, por lo que le paso a la función el id del libro en concreto. Sin embargo, aunque la conexión es correcta ya que el SELECT funciona y me aparecen los datos que quiero, no se llega a hacer el UPDATE. Lo único que he conseguido sacar en la consola es que cuando hago click al botón se le mete el id del primer libro aunque le de al cuarto, y si le doy de nuevo al cuarto se le mete el id del segundo y así sucesivamente. Pero aún así, no cambia el campo "leido" de esos libros.

Aquí mi php (conecto con PDO):

```
<?php
                    include("funcionesPDO.php");
                    $conex = conectar();

                    $stmt = $conex->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE leido = 0 AND id_usuario = :is");
                    $stmt->bindValue(':is', $_SESSION['usuario_id']);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $libros = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    function marcarLeido($idParam){
                      
                      $stmt = $conex->prepare("UPDATE books SET leido = 1 WHERE id = :id AND id_usuario = :par");
                      $stmt->bindValue(':par', $_SESSION['usuario_id']);
                      $stmt->bindValue(':id', $idParam);
                      $stmt->execute();
                      }

                    foreach($libros as $libro){
                     echo  "<div class='column'>";
                      echo "<div class='card card-equal-height'>";
                        echo "<div class='card-image form_photo'>";
                          echo "<figure class='image is-4by3'>";
                            echo "<img src='".$libro['imagen']."'>";
                          echo "</figure>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='card-content'>";
                          echo "<p class='title is-5 has-text-centered'>". $libro['titulo'] ."</p>";
                            echo "<p class='subtitle is-6 has-text-centered'>". $libro['autor']."</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='card-footer level-item'>";
                                  echo "<a href='' onclick='marcarLeido(".$libro['id'].")'><p class='card-footer-item'>";
                                  echo "<i class='fas fa-bookmark'></i>";
                                   echo "<span>&nbsp;Leído</a></span></p></a>";
                                  echo "<a href=''><p class='card-footer-item'>";
                                  echo "<i class='fas fa-paper-plane'></i>";
                                    echo "<span>&nbsp; Enviar</a></span></p>";
                               echo  "</div></div></div>";
                    }
                    desconectar($conex);
                    ?>
```

Comment: Realmente no estás enviando el parámetro, porque solo colocas `data: { isbn }` y se deben enviar pares de "clave" => "valor", entonces; actualmente solo estás enviando el valor. Intenta con: `data: { isbn: isbn }`, donde la primera parte `isbn:` es la clave.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si el usuario aún no ha leído el libro? Deberías hacer un INSERT en lugar de UPDATE.

Comment: @Triby precisamente los libros se guardan a través de un buscador que hace el insert, los libros que estoy mostrando aquí son esos ya guardados por el usuario y que se han insertado correctamente. He probado hacerlo con el método GET como me ha comentado otro usuario, y Sources en la Console me dice que el isbn lo coge bien y muestra el adecuado, pero que la url no está definida. He comprobado mil veces el nombre y situación del archivo y ambas son correctas.

Comment: ¿El script es `marcarLeido.php` con L mayúscula? ¿Está en la misma carpeta donde listas los libros?

Comment: @Triby sí, el script se llama marcarLeido.php con mayúscula y sí, también está en el mismo directorio donde está el php/html donde se hace y muestra la lista de libros.

Answer (score 1):

Desde el código HTML que generas con los echos, no puedes llamar directamente a una función en PHP, debes llamar a una función Javascript que ejecute un GET o POST con una petición AJAX. Ya desde está función podrás ejecutar el código PHP con el UPDATE.
Lo primero que deberías mirar es sí, la llamada se está haciendo de forma correcta, puedes comprobarlo desde la pestaña Network del navegador. Puedes tener un problema en si la URL es correcta o no. Posteriormente mirar que recibe bien el parámetro GET.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Tiene bastante sentido y seguro que por ahí está el camino. Sin embargo, he hecho los cambios pertinentes y sigue sin funcionar y sin mostrar errores en la Consola. He actualizado el post con los códigos html, javascript y php si pudieras echarle un vistazo.